# IE scrollbar bug

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

[IE bug, how to remove scrollbar in this dropdown, I don't need this? In chrome works fine, no scrollbar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmesM.png)

My code:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class=""> </label>
<select>
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Used">one</option>
<option value="UnderRepair">two</option>
<option value="WriteOff">three</option>
<option value="Destroyed">four</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide scroll this might work

```
    .form-group select{
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!
And have one small question:

how to set  height that <option>s will fit in <select> box.
select{ height: 200px; } doesn't work...

Comment: you can set height in select with simple atribute.`code <select onfocus='this.size=10;'>`